# Any chance to shield create_task'ed task?

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, aiohttp

I need to shield a task been fired with `create_task` within an aiohttp handler process like

```
async def handler(request):
    asyncio.create_task(long_process())
    return {}, 200
```

So the code is

```
import asyncio


async def shielded(coro):
    try:
        await asyncio.shield(coro)
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        await coro
        raise


def create_task(coro) -> asyncio.Task:
    task = asyncio.create_task(shielded(coro))
    return task
```

But this test

```
async def test_create_task_cancel():
    async def coro():
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        return None

    task = create_task(coro())
    await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
    task.cancel()
    await asyncio.sleep(1)

    assert task.done() and task.result() is None
```

with

```
RuntimeError: coroutine is being awaited already
```

`aiohttp` manual suggests to use `aiojobs.Scheduler`, but it doesn't work as expected
https://github.com/aio-libs/aiojobs/issues/148
https://github.com/aio-libs/aiojobs/issues/72

Comment: Your initial code block does not return the task. How and why does something attempt to cancel it?

Comment: This code `task = asyncio.create_task(shielded(coro))` creates a task

Comment: I'm specifically asking about `async def handler(request)` which creates *but does not return* a task.

Comment: Yes, this is _by design_ and is handled within middleware, but out of scope of current question

Answer (score 0):

Working shield function

```
async def shielded(coro):
    ft = asyncio.ensure_future(coro)
    shielded_ft = asyncio.shield(ft)
    try:
        await shielded_ft
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        await ft
        raise
```

Comment: Test should be patched also `assert task.done() and task.cancelled()`